# Automatically position Grid elements

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, css-grid

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="grid grid-flow-dense grid-cols-6 grid-rows-6 gap-4">
  <span class="aspect-square h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2"></span>
  <span class="aspect-square h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2"></span>
  <span class="aspect-square h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2"></span>
  <span class="aspect-square h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2"></span>
  <span class="aspect-square h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2"></span>
  <span class="aspect-square h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2"></span>
  <span class="aspect-square h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2"></span>
  <span class="aspect-square h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2"></span>
  <span class="aspect-square h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2"></span>
</div>
```

Grid property `grid-auto-flow: dense;` doesn't work as expected. What can I use to replace element 1 with 2 and 3?

[image]

Take into consideration this is a react project, and the rectangles are photos taken from instagram api, so `grid-area` wouldn't work I think (not scalable enough).

Comment: Does DOM order matter?

Comment: @Wongjn I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="grid grid-flow-dense grid-cols-6 grid-rows-6 gap-4">
  <span class="aspect-square h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2"></span>
  <span class="aspect-square h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2"></span>
  <span class="aspect-square h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2"></span>
  <span class="aspect-square h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2"></span>
  <span class="aspect-square h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2"></span>
  <span class="aspect-square h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2"></span>
  <span class="aspect-square col-start-3 h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2"></span>
  <span class="aspect-square col-start-4 h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2"></span>
  <span class="aspect-square h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2"></span>
</div>
```

You should use `col-start-[index]` in 2nd, 3rd elements.

```
  <span class="aspect-square col-start-3 h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2">[2]</span>
  <span class="aspect-square col-start-4 h-full w-full bg-red-500 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:col-span-2 [&:nth-child(3n+3)]:row-span-2">[3]</span>
```

`col-start-{n}` is utility to make an element start at the `n`th grid line.